# Legend of Nine Treasure Hunt in Andaman and Nicobar Islands

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, treasure-hunt

Disclaimer: I dont know the answer but it is definitely solvable.

A legend of nine, In the Andaman, A treasure you may find, But, certainly, the blood of men.

Staring at the Sun, At 30 to 6, Al asked the captain, “What is the fix?” “The Sun” says the cap, “And blood shall determine our fate” And so he screams “Die, Al” And so remain 8.

Down the direction, so gracefully learnt, Atop a lonely tree, they find a nest. They hear the ill omens of the crows, And another life goes to waste.

Expectedly, Another turn of events, Left the first mate forever lost, Along with the tents.

At 45 to 4, onward they went, Towards the oasis in sight. The most eager of all shattered their illusion, And died due to the snake bite. Soon, fell upon them, the night, The predators were approaching fast, And with backs turned to the Polaris, They headed towards the past.

As the Sun lifted into the sky, So did the spirits of the grey. They were ready again to face the odds as before, But with only mirrors leading the way.

“R.I.P. comrade,” said the captain, And engulfed himself in loneliness, Only to find that he was back, At that inn with his mistress;

“The inn is the centre of everything,” He admitted, amazed, And it is there where I should have realized, The curse of the maze.”

The above poem is famous in the islands of Andaman and Nicobar. The treasure is rumoured to be still there. Find the place where the treasure is buried.

Comment: The question seemed to exist before for 2 days but it was never answered and taken down. But I would definitely love to know the answer.

Comment: I commented on the previous version yesterday with some theories/observations, and the OP subsequently deleted the whole post. So presumably there's some issue with it (maybe not solvable without additional information/content, like an actual map or something?). If that's the case, and without the original author around to confirm things, I'm inclined to VtC...

Comment: ...or at the very least, you should add a disclaimer to your post that makes clear you don't know the answer and that it's unknown whether it's even solvable.

Comment: Sorry. I have added the disclaimer.

Comment: do you know it's "definitely solvable" though?

Comment: Yes, for certain.

Comment: So, if it's not yours, but you know it's solvable in the form given, presumably you know its source? Perhaps you should credit/link to the original?

Comment: I don't  know the original source, but I came across it in a  very well regarded top notch treasure hunting contest back in India.You can look up the event LOST here in this link:http://www.inquivesta.iiserkol.ac.in/Events/mobile.php Howevrr you need to have an account to access the questions.